# Firebug's "net" tab is not showing anything?

Tags: firefox, firebug

I usually run Fiddler for net traffic monitoring and now am using a Mac machine.  I thought Firebug's net tab can show the traffic that is fetched through AJAX (the net tab is enabled).  But if I try google.com, and type in something, its "google suggest" will show a bunch of suggestions, but the Firebug's "net" tab is not showing anything?

Comment: Are you sure you have the Net tab enabled, especially since it isn't by default?

Comment: What version of firebug are you using? It works for me on Firebug 1.5.4: I see requests going through every time I type something.

Comment: yes, i am using 1.5.4 as well, on the current Firefox (3.5.9) on Snow Leopard on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the net tab daily as my preferred traffic sniffer and using Firebug 1.5.4 on Firefox 3.6.3 under Linux.

While enabling the net tab is important, please pay attention to also request Firbug show All requests and not just HTML or similar requests. I'd also suggest clearing all the requests from the panel before you start sniffing for actual AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after installing Firebug, it asked for a restart of Firefox and it was done, but for some reason, the restart didn't make the net tab work.  So I quit Firefox and restarted again and now it is working.

---

even after restarting again, FB Connect seems to have choked it again.  Restarting again worked...  more info later...  seems like a way to solve it for now is just to restart it.