# Network tab in Firebug doesn't show any files

Tags: html, file, firebug, reference

I'm creating a html-layout based on an existing layout. I want to extract all the files, that are currently actually being used, from the old layout, since there is a lot of crap in the directories that's been there from the ancient times or something.

So I tried to open the existing layout in Firefox and use Firebug to see which files are actually loaded, but the Network tab stays empty, so that's not very helpful.

I already found this question: [Firebug's "net" tab is not showing anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908576/firebugs-net-tab-is-not-showing-anything) and I got pretty much the same problem, whereas the accepted answer doesn't work for me.

I think the problem here is that I'm not making any http-request, I'm just viewing html-files from my local machine, so the the url is something like

```
file:///C:/myfolder/myfile.html
```

There is only one entry displayed in the Firebug Network tab:

```
Url | Status | Domain | Size | Timeline
------------------------------------------
-   |        |        | 0KB  |
```

This might as well be intentional since I'm not accesseing any files accross the network. 
So is there any other way to view which files are referenced and which files the browser tries to access?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are using Firebug to debug local files (“file://etc”) the Net panel is disabled (obviously). [source](http://web.archive.org/web/20101129041654/http://ux.zerg.nl/?p=114)

you could run the files from a local web server (Visual Studio's cassini, IIS or [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html))

Comment: this was what I thought, I just wanted some confirmation on this, thanks.

Comment: I consider this a bug. There's no reason the net tab shouldn't work with local files just as well as it does with network files.

Comment: Link to "source" is dead. Here's an [archive of that page](http://web.archive.org/web/20101129041654/http://ux.zerg.nl/?p=114).

Comment: Chrome DevTools will show request for local files if you need this functionality